# Declaring a LinearLayout from Android 3.0 Cookbook Chapter 2

Tags: android-linearlayout

I'm following the instructions from chapter 2 (Declaring a layout) from the Android 3.0 Application Development Cookbook, and  I can't seem to get it to work. Here's the code:

The book has you edit the main.xml file so that it looks like this in res/layout/activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:text="@string/vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Button
    android:text="@string/button_click_horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/horizontal_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then, as second step, it asks you make a copy of the activity_main.xml file and name it my_layout.xml, and its code looks like this (res/layout/my_layout.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:text="@string/horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Button
    android:text="@string/click_for_vertical"
    android:id="@+id/vertical_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And the code for the main activity file looks like this:

```
package com.example.declaringlayouts;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
private Button mHorizontalButton;
private Button mVerticalButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mVerticalButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.vertical_button);
    mHorizontalButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.horizontal_button);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view == mHorizontalButton) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    } else if (view == mVerticalButton) {
        setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

The idea is that clicking in horizontal button will switch to the vertical layout, and vice-versa. Clicking on the button does not work at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell the buttons that this class is the onClickListener, so that it will call your onClick method when they are clicked.

This has to be set up every time you create a new content view, so you should put your button reference setup and listener assignment into a method. So this is how I would revise the class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    prepareButtons();
}

void prepareButtons(){
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.vertical_button);
    if (button==null)
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.horizontal_button);
    mVerticalButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    mHorizontalButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view == mHorizontalButton) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        prepareButtons();
    } else if (view == mVerticalButton) {
        setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);
        prepareButtons();
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I did try adding the OnClickListener for the buttons: `mVerticalButton.setOnClickListener(this); mHorizontalButton.setOnClickListener(this);` but the app would crash because somehow it can't initialize the vertical button: `mVerticalButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.vertical_button);` It comes out empty when I debugged it.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't notice that there is only one of the two buttons in each of the layouts. I'll update this in a minute.

Comment: This isn't really the best way to do it, but it's a place to start when you're learning. Since you're toggling between different layouts, I think it would be more robust to use a separate onClickListener for the buttons of each layout, instead of just using the activity class itself as a catch-all listener.

Comment: Thanks again for the suggestion. I'll try adding a separate onClickListener for each of the buttons, but then now question would be why the one of the button that's on the other layout can't be initialized, so this one: `mVerticalButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.vertical_button);` Is it because it is on different layout? What's the best way to initialized it?

Comment: When you call setContentView, it reads the XML file and generates actual objects from it. That's why, each time you call setContentView, your old references to buttons will not work any more--they are referring to the previously created layout that you no longer have access to. Also, not sure about this, but I think keeping references to those buttons will cause that old layout to leak, until you drop the button references.

Comment: When you call findViewById, it only searches whichever layout is currently set. If the current layout doesn't have an R.id.vertical_button, then findViewById(R.id.vertical_button) will return null, because that button doesn't exist in the current layout.